# How do I evaluate the integral $\frac{-i}{2(2\pi)^2r}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dp\frac{p\exp(ipr)}{\sqrt{p^2+m^2}}$?

Tags: integration, residue-calculus

I would normally use residue theorem but I dont know how to approach such problems when there is a square root in the integrand. This is not a homework, I encountered this integral in quantum field theory while self studying. One can let $\rho=-ip$ and have a branch cuts at $\pm im$ and evaluate the integral approximately as $r \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: The integral does not converge in the usual sense.

Comment: @Jan please check the edit.

Comment: While this is ostensibly just a math question, you might have better luck on the physics stackexchange board. Integrals like this one pop up in QFT all the time, as you mentioned, and it's second nature to physicists.